# How to format a date interval to text (internationalized)

Tags: php, datetime, localization, internationalization, gettext

Let's say I have a DateInterval, like "P10DT1H53S", and I want to format it to a human-readable string, like :

```
10 days, 1 hour and 53 seconds
```

Now, this is fairly easy if you only plan to do it for English. But I am looking for a clean and internationalized way to do that, using gettext.

Unfortunately, gettext only handles one plural at a time, not multiple (years, days, hours etc.), so I cannot use ngettext to achieve what I want. And plurals differ with languages greatly, so it's not as simple as iterating and adding "s"  where needed. Also, I must build it as a whole, because I'm not sure every language would separate the days, hours, … using commas (with one "and" instead of the last comma).

Comment: The only mechanism I know that comes close to handling this case well is Perl's [Locale::MakeText](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Locale-Maketext-1.17/lib/Locale/Maketext/TPJ13.pod) module, and you might not have easy access to translations. Best of luck, and I can't wait for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple calls to gettext instead of doing it only in one. This should bypass the plural restriction.

Comment: How exactly ? Not all languages would use commas to separate the nouns and use `_('and')` for the last one (or am I wrong about this?)

Comment: You can also use gettext for the separator. But to keep it simple, I'll simply do something like "10 day(s), 1 hour(s) and 53 second(s)" I think people won't mind and it will be easier to internationalize

Comment: `gettext()` really fails badly for this case, as the correct pluralization depends upon the exact number. [In Russian](http://www.russianlessons.net/lessons/lesson11_main.php), the pluralization changes if the number ends in 1; 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0; or is between 11 and 19. There are _four_ different possible pluralizations of a word based on the specific number.

Answer (score 1):

The best repository for up-to-date internationalization data is the [CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org/), hosted by the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/). Locale-specific pluralization rules are part of the data set.

The repository data is available in a bunch of XML files. There are a few tools for manipulating the data, including code to generate POSIX-compatible locale files.

I'm not sure how much work you'd need to do to use the data in PHP (not my speciality), but it would probably be worth it in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the link, this definitely looks worth using, but it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for ; I just need a way to format a time interval, not the translation data (I plan to use .po files).

Comment: Using .po files may work for the text fragments, but you'd need to use the repository's pluralization rules to select which one to use. http://www.unicode.org/cldr/data/charts/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html